# function cal() with radio input

Tags: javascript, forms, input, radio-button

i created a form with cal() but im not able to make it work with radio input.
It worked with select and option, but now the value isnt taken.

here the code

```
<script> 
function cal()
 { 
  var pl=document.form1.template.value; 
  var resultat=pl; 
  document.form1.tresultat.value=resultat; 
  document.formfin.tresultatfin.value = calfin(); 
  } 
</script> 

<form name="form1">
  <label for="Template">Option 1 : Template</label>
  <ul>
  <li id="template"><label for="logo+texte">Logo et texte</label> 
 <input type="radio" id="test" name="template" value="500" onclick="cal()"></li>
 <li><label for="base">Base</label> 
 <input type="radio" id="test" name="template" value="800" onclick="cal()"></li>
 <li><label for="perso">Sur-Mesure</label> 
 <input type="radio" id="test" name="template" value="2900" onclick="cal()"></li></ul>
  <input type="text" value="0" name="tresultat">
 </form>
```

any idea to get the value in the text input when selected ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons are weird because there's a list of separate elements instead of just one.  The simplest thing to do is to pass the element itself as a parameter:

```
function cal( button )
 { 
  var pl = button.value; 
  var resultat=pl; 
  document.form1.tresultat.value=resultat; 
  document.formfin.tresultatfin.value = calfin(); 
 }
```

and then change the radio buttons:

```
 <input type="radio" id="test" name="template" value="800" onclick="cal( this )"></li>
```

passing `this` to the function.